# How to query against 18million rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm basically wondering what's the best way to query a table with such amount of rows?

I'm guessing I'd need to do some optimization before I even think about queries since anything I try to perform takes around 50 seconds to complete?

Anyone have any ideas on how to speed up my table and perform queries much quicker?

Here's an example query :

```
SELECT 
    `COMPANY_NAME`, `ZIPCODE`, `ADDRESS`
FROM
    `companies`
WHERE
    replace(`COMPANY_NAME`, ' ', '') = '$area'
```

Here's my Database structure

```
id  int(11) PRIMARY
COMPANY_NAME    varchar(255)
ADDRESS varchar(255)
CITY    varchar(255)
STATE   varchar(255)
ZIPCODE varchar(255)
COUNTRY varchar(255)
WEB_ADDRESS varchar(255)
PHONE_NUMBER    varchar(255)
FAX_NUMBER  varchar(255)
CONTACT_NAME    varchar(255)
TITLE   varchar(255)
GENDER  varchar(255)
EMPLOYEE    varchar(255)
SALES   varchar(255)
MAJOR_DIVISION_DESCRIPTION  text
SIC_2_Code_Description  text
SIC_4_Code  varchar(255)
SIC_4_Code_Description  text    latin1_swedish_ci
```

My database is also InnoDB

Comment: 18 million rows is not a lot of rows

Comment: @JohnConde I got told that, but my table is so bad!

Comment: But a query with such a where and no specific index is heavy even with a small table.

Comment: Do you do other kind of queries or do you want to optimize only this query ? If it's only for this query, the simplest solution would be to keep `eplace(`COMPANY_NAME`, ' ', '')` computed in a column and indexed.

Comment: You could start narrowing the size of your columns for one. I highly doubt `STATE`, `PHONE`, `FAX` or `ZIPCODE` fields would warrant using 255 characters. I realize you're using varchar, but the more narrow you can make the columns, the better. You might in cases where it's possible also be better off using char fields if you can predict the length. It won't save much that way, but with 80 mio rows, every small amount of bytes you can shave off per row will be quite significant when adding it all up.

Comment: Your query will always perform `replace('COMPANY_NAME', ' ', '')` on all 18 million rows. You should figure out a way to write your query so you can use `=` directly; `COMPANY_NAME = $something` and add an index on the COMPANY_NAME column

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `REPLACE`? Please explain the data and search criteria.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, it's a PHP variable which is `$area = str_replace(" ","",urldecode($_GET['company']));`

Comment: It seems you'll want to retain the company parameter so you don't have to do queries like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue on performance on your query is this statement:

```
WHERE replace(`COMPANY_NAME`, ' ', '') = '$area'
```

If, instead, you had:

```
WHERE COMPANY_NAME = '$area'
```

then an index on COMPANY_NAME could be used.  However, because your version uses a function on the column, the database engine has to do a full table scan instead of an index lookup.

More information would be needed to solve this problem.  One would be to update `COMPANY_NAME` to remove spaces and add an index on it.  Another would be to add another column (as suggested by @dystroy).  If you are only trying to remove trailing spaces, then you probably want to update the existing column.  Finally, if you are trying to match words in `COMPANY_NAME`, and not the whole name, then a full text index may be the best solution.

By the way, have you tried this?

```
WHERE COMPANY_NAME like '$area%'
```

That is, do a wildcard search at the *end* of `$area`.  That can use an index on `COMPANY_NAME` and, if it returns the right results, might be the easiest way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should almost never query a database and filter using no index, which is the case here as you execute a function on all rows. You say it takes 50 seconds but it could be worse and it could be hard to predict (due to mysql cachings).

Supposing you always do this query (and you need to do it), the best would be to keep a column with content `replace(`COMPANY_NAME`, ' ', '')` (use a trigger) and index that column. The search would then be instant.

Comment: To add a little context, the reason this will work is because in the OP's current query, the database has to run this function against all 18 million rows.  If you pre-convert and index the content as @dystroy suggests, the database can just do an index lookup instead.

Comment: Note that some other DBMS (for example posgresql) would allow you to index the result of a function which lets the table clean.

Comment: So if I was to go ahead and do `ALTER TABLE companies ADD INDEX (COMPANY_NAME);` that should improve my queries somewhat?

Comment: @Curtis No. Because this index can't be used due to your replacement.

Comment: I've also gone ahead and changed my query to like so `WHERE COMPANY_NAME LIKE '$area%'`

Comment: @Curtis That doesn't do the same thing at all but that will be faster already.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reorganize tables to us appropriate data types (saves space over `VARCHAR(255)`)
2. Add indexes on any fields that will be used in joining or filtering (`COMPANY_NAME`)
3. Avoid negating indexes and string manipulation in your query, ie your replace statement would negate an index on `COMPANY_NAME` and increase run-time.  Perhaps you need to add another column where `COMPANY_NAME` has no spaces, or modify your variable in the query above.

Just a few suggestions, the 2nd and 3rd will impact performance the most, in your situation.